# Show that $\Sigma\vDash p_1\vee p_2\vee...\vee p_n$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This is **Exercise 3.27** from [Derek Goldrei's, Propositional and Predicate Calculus : A Model of Argument](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1852339217).

> Suppose that, for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$, $p_i$ is a propositional variable. Let $\Sigma$ be a set of sentences of the propositional calculus. Suppose that all truth assignments which satisfy $\Sigma$ make at least one $p_i$ true. Show that for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $$\Sigma\vDash p_1\vee p_2\vee...\vee p_n.$$

I am aware that an answer exists [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/954427/show-that-sum-models-p-1-lor-p-2-lor-lor-p-n-for-some-n-in-mathbb). I want to instead attempt to prove the contrapositive:

Suppose that $\Sigma\vDash p_1\vee p_2\vee...\vee p_n$ for no $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This is the same as saying $\Sigma\nvDash p_1\vee p_2\vee...\vee p_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. This trivially means that for some truth assignment, $v_n$, which satisfies $\Sigma$, that $v_n(p_1\vee p_2\vee...\vee p_n)=F$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. (The $v$ does not necessarily have to be the same for all $n$'s and is hence subscripted by $n$.) By the truth table for $\vee$, we conclude that $v_n(p_1)=v_n(p_2)=...=v_n(p_n)=F$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But this says that one truth assignment, $v_{n\to\infty}$ which satisfies $\Sigma$ makes none of $p_i$, $i\in\mathbb{N}$ true (i.e. the one in the limit that $n\to\infty$), and we are done proof by contrapositive.

Is this a valid proof method in this situation?

Comment: What you must do is to argue from the existence of all $\nu_n$ that there is a valuation $\nu$ such that $\nu(p_i)=F$ for all $i$ and $\nu$ satisfies $\Sigma$.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Crudely, is this not the $v_n$ in the limit that $n\to\infty$?

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: I mean that $v_{\infty}$ is the truth assignment which satisfies $\Sigma$ but not any $p_i$. But I don't think I can use infinities like that in logic.

Comment: You talk of "the truth assignment", as if it is unique, which is completely unjustified as far as I can tell

Comment: (And no, we cannot "use" infinities like that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not a valid argument. The problem is when you say

> But this says that one truth assignment which satisfies $\Sigma$ make none of $p_i$, $i\in\mathbb{N}$ true

That's not what it says. You have for each $n$ a valuation $\nu_n$ which makes $\Sigma$ true but no $p_i$ true for $i\le n$, but you haven't cooked up a single valuation $\nu$ which makes $\Sigma$ true but no $p_i$ true for any $i$ at all.

For example, maybe $\nu_1\models p_2$, $\nu_2\models p_3$, $\nu_3\models p_4$, ...

Now we want to say that somehow we can "smoosh together" the $\nu_i$s to get a $\nu$ making $\Sigma$ true and making each $p_i$ false. But how?

*(HINT: use the compactness theorem ...)*

(We can sometimes think of this as "taking the limit" of the $\nu_n$s, but that takes a bit of work to make non-problematic. One approach to doing so is to introduce ultrafilters - and this is basically avoiding using the compactness *theorem* by employing its *proof*.)

Comment: What if I define my $v$ as follows. $v(p_i)=v_i(p_i)$? Then clearly $v$ satisfies $\Sigma$ but also $v(p_i)=F$ for all $p_i$.

Comment: @quanticbolt "clearly $\nu$ satisfies $\Sigma$" Why? That's essentially what you're trying to prove.

Comment: @quanticbolt What do you mean "$\nu$ is only ever $\nu_i$"? Suppose $\nu_i$ makes each $p_j$ false for $j\le i$ but each $p_k$ true for $k>i$. In what sense is $\nu$ only ever $\nu_i$?

Comment: hmmm. I'm sensing that this is where the compactness theorem comes in, but I'm not exactly sure how to apply it. I know that it says $\Gamma$ is satisfiable iff every finite subset of $\Gamma$ is satisfiable. So in this case, is my $\Gamma=\Sigma$?

Comment: @quanticbolt Not quite. It's not $\Sigma$ alone that you want to satisfy. What's the whole theory you want your $\nu$ to satisfy? It's $\Sigma$, but also something about the $p_i$s ...

Comment: @quanticbolt I'm not sure what that means. Just think about this ideal $\nu$ on its own. Certainly it should make $\Sigma$ true. Can you think of some other statement(s) it should make true?

Comment: It should make the set $\{\neg p_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ true. Every $\neg p_i$ should be true under $v$ because that's how to ensure that every $p_i$ is false under $v$.

Comment: @quanticbolt Yes. So the theory you want to satisfy is $\Sigma\cup\{\neg p_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. So basically we want to show that the $v$ I defined earlier satisfies $\Sigma\cup\{\neg p_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$. We can apply the compactness theorem here, and show that if every finite subset of this is satisfiable under $v$, then so too is the bigger set itself?

Comment: @quanticbolt The compactness theorem doesn't let you prove anything obviously about a *specific valuation*; it's used instead to show that *some valuation exists*. That is: you know it's enough to prove that there is some valuation of $T=\Sigma\cup\{\neg p_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$. By compactness, you know that it's enough to prove that every finite subtheory of $T$ has a valuation making it true. So do you see how to prove this last claim? *(HINT: how many $\neg p_i$s can a finite subtheory of $T$ contain?)*

Comment: Okay. So every finite subtheory of $T$ can contain only a finite number of $\neg p_i$s, say $n$. We know based on what I did before that $v_n$ will satisfy this set of $\neg p_i$s by definition. Based on this, every finite subset of $T$ is satisfiable, and so too is $T$?

Comment: @quanticbolt Yup, that's it!